# Баг в моём коде python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каждое слово должно быть отдельным элементом массива. Сначала код идет, пока не встречает запятую, после чего начинает заносить весь текст до запятой. Так должно идти и дальше. Этот текст является примером : везде стоят запятые, и код должен заносить тест с прошлой запятой уже на новую (, текст,) и добавлять новый элемент. Но код все это объединяет в один элемент.

Пример вывода: ['Hello', 'Bro']

```
inp = "Hello, Bro, Hey"
inp = list(inp)
indx = -1

def ToDecrypt(inp, indx):
    finish = False
    while finish == False:
        indx += 1
        print(indx)
        if inp[indx] == ",":
            res = []
            times = 0
            if times >= 1:
                res.append("".join(inp[indx:]))
                print(res)
            else:
                res.append("".join(inp[:indx]))
                print(res)
                times += 1
            
            
            print(res)
        if indx >= len(inp) - 1:
            finish = True
    
ToDecrypt(inp, indx)
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
['Hello']
['Hello']
6
7
8
9
10
['Hello, Bro']
['Hello, Bro']
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую использовать функцию `split()`:

```
inp = "Hello, Bro, Hey"
inp = inp.split(', ')
print(inp)                   # Вывод ['Hello', 'Bro', 'Hey']
```

Comment: И вечно находиться решение в одну функцию а не в 15 строк, и да спасибо.

Comment: @Half, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте поставить галочку.

Comment: Извините, но ответ не подходит, я перепутал, нужно чтобы каждое слово было элементом массива

Comment: @Half, в питоне нет массивов. В качестве их альтернативы используются списки.

Comment: Глеб, Листы* или же списки

Comment: @Half, лист и список — одно и то же. Одно — русское название другого.

Comment: Глеб, и вот мне нужно чтобы каждое слово было элементом листа

Comment: list = ['Hello', 'Bro']

Comment: @Half, каждое слово и является элементом листа, который создается в переменной `inp`. Введите мой код в питон и посмотрите.

Comment: @Half, в переменную `list` нельзя ничего записать, потому что это название типа данных

Comment: @Half, если вам так надо, добавьте в конец кода `lst = inp`, но ей-богу, не пойму зачем.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, сам запутался, галочку поставил, спасибо

Comment: "в питоне нет массивов. В качестве их альтернативы используются списки." - в Python список - это и есть динамический массив, так что это не "альтернатива" массивам. Если уж прикапываться к словам, то и массивы (arrays) в Python есть: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html